# Numbers losing/changing values

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I am currently creating a program meant to take input of 12 songs on an album as  two sets of inputted numbers as minutes and seconds, storing them in appropriate arrays for both, and then returning the album's length, the average song length, the shortest song, and the longest song.  Pretty much all of my current code is going fine, however I am having some serious difficulty with my numbers being correct. Whenever I format the to just seconds, and back to minutes and seconds while being formatted to have a semicolon and a 0 in front of a single digit second, they seem to change. Please see the attached image for further explanation.

[image]

Here is the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void displayTime(int);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 12;
    int mins[SIZE], secs[SIZE],minsToSecs[SIZE], totalSecs[SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    int shortest, longest, totalAlbumLength, averageLengthOfTracks;


    cout << "Welcome to my Album Length Calculator" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter all track lengths in minutes and seconds" << endl;
    cout << "seperated by a space." << endl;


    while (count < SIZE)
    {
        cout << "Track " << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> mins[count];
        cin >> secs[count];
        count++;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
         minsToSecs[i] = mins[i] * 60;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        totalSecs[i] = minsToSecs[i] + secs[i];
    }


    shortest = totalSecs[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (shortest > totalSecs[i])
            shortest = totalSecs[i];


    longest = totalSecs[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        if (longest < totalSecs[i])
            longest = totalSecs[i];


    totalAlbumLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        totalAlbumLength += totalSecs[i];


    averageLengthOfTracks = totalAlbumLength / SIZE;


    cout << "The Shortest track was "; 
        displayTime(shortest);


    cout << "The Longest track was ";
        displayTime(longest);


    cout << "The Total Album Length was ";
        displayTime(totalAlbumLength);


    cout << "The Average Track Length was ";
        displayTime(averageLengthOfTracks);


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void displayTime(int input)
{
    int mins, secs;
    mins = input / 60;
    secs = input % 60;

    cout << mins << " : " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << mins << endl;
}
```

Is there something that I am missing here or some simple that I've simply overlooked?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Make `SIZE` equal to 1 or 2 and debug your program.  You don't need 12 items to see the error.  Also, [this minimized version of your program](http://ideone.com/lzevHj) is an example of a [mcve] that you could have tested and posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple typo. You are computing minutes and seconds, and then only outputting `mins : mins`.

Change the last line of your `displayTime()` function to:

```
cout << mins << " : " << setfill('0') << setw(2) << secs << endl;
```

I should mention that I found this by looking at your output. Seeing that all of the numbers you were printing out were "x : x" made me suspect something was copied twice accidentally. Looking at your displayTime function showed me the problem. As @NathanOliver said, a debugger can be a really useful tool to use when trying to figure out this problem yourself.